wrapfigure causes text to overlap

Adding space after \blindtext solves it, I think it is possible to patch wrapfigure to avoid the issue. Also, the text below the figure changes color
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{wrapfig2}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{wrapfigure}{o}{0.35\linewidth}
    
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    
    The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
    
\end{wrapfigure}

{
\color{gray}
\blindtext
}

\end{document}


don't start the group after wrapfig, or end it before the paragraph ends

\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{blindtext,graphicx,wrapfig2}
\begin{document}

\begin{wrapfigure}{o}{0.35\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
{\normalcolor The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog}
\end{wrapfigure}
\color{gray}
\blindtext
\normalcolor

\blindtext

\end{document}


